# How to Move Bing Maps Menu to the Right side of Screen

Tags: html, css, bing, bing-maps

I'm using the Bing Maps API, which adds a menu bar to the top left of the screen: 
[image: menu bar on left]

I would like to mirror how it is now and have the bar on the right, with the compass furthest to the right, the zoom next, and the birds eye menu next.  The current HTML is:

```
<div class="MicrosoftNav MapTypeId_be">
    <div class="OverlaysTL">
        <div class="NavBar_compassControlContainer">
            <a class="NavBar_button NavBar_toolButton NavBar_rotateLeft" href="#" title="Rotate left" uici="NB.CS.RotateLeft" style="visibility: hidden;">
            </a>
            <a href="#" title="Click to pan in any direction" uici="NB.CS.PanControl" class="NavBar_compass NavBar_compassFlat">N</a>
            <a class="NavBar_button NavBar_toolButton NavBar_rotateRight" href="#" title="Rotate right" uici="NB.CS.RotateRight" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="NavBar_zoomControlContainer">
            <div class="NavBar_zoomDrop" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
               <div class="NavBar_zoom">
                   <div class="NavBar_zoomBar" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
                       <div class="NavBar_zoomBarBg"></div>
                       <div class="NavBar_zoomSlider" title="Move slider to zoom in or out" style="top: 97px;"></div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <a class="NavBar_button NavBar_toolButton NavBar_zoomOut" href="#" title="Zoom out" uici="NB.ZC.ZoomOut"></a>
           <a class="NavBar_button NavBar_toolButton NavBar_zoomIn" href="#" title="Zoom in" uici="NB.ZC.ZoomIn"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="NavBar_modeSelectorControlContainer">
           <span class="NavBar_separator"></span>
           <span class="NavBar_button NavBar_typeButton">
               <a class="NavBar_typeButtonLabel NavBar_MapType_be" href="#">Bird's eye</a>
               <span class="separator"></span>
               <a class="NavBar_dropIconContainer" href="#">
                   <span class="NavBar_dropIcon"></span>
               </a>
           </span>
       </div>
       <span style="display: block; height: 0px; width: 0px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; clear: both;"></span>
   </div>
   <span style="display: block; height: 0px; width: 0px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; clear: both;"></span>
</div>
```

Because of this I tried the following CSS:

```
#map-canvas > div > div.MicrosoftNav.MapTypeId_be > div{
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This resulted in: 
[image: Menubar with attempted CSS]

what would I have to do to get the mirror of the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically the modifying the CSS of the Bing Maps controls is an undocumented/unsupported hack which could break if V7 were updated. So generally this is not recommended. The recommended approach is to hide the default navigation bar and create a custom control and float it over the map.

Note that the navigation bar grows to the right depending on what is being displayed (i.e. Birds eye, breadcrumb) which would make moving it to the right an issue. If you don't care about that then you can use the following CSS which will work for everything but the breadcrumb:

```
.MicrosoftMap .OverlaysTL {
    top: auto;
    right: 348px;
}

.NavBar_compassControlContainer {
    left: 240px;
}

.NavBar_zoomControlContainer {
    left: 190px;
}

.NavBar_modeSelectorControlContainer {
    left: 0px;
}

.MicrosoftNav .NavBar_separator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
}
```